# Is it possible to snap to offset lines in QGIS (3.20.2)?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I have created a "Laneway" layer which consists of 2 lines offset by a user defined distance from a centreline. I need a simple way to accurately trace or snap to the 2 offset lines to create adjacent "Paddocks" (polygons) either side of the "Laneway" feature. Using an offset curve is to complicated for my farmer clients!
I can snap to the digitised centreline (as expected):[image: Can snap here]

I can't snap here; is there any easy way to do this?
[image: Can't snap here!]

Comment: When you say "I have created a "Laneway" layer" it sounds like you already have this layer created, so can you not just snap to that layer?

Comment: I can snap to the digitised centreline as expected:

Comment: I know you're trying but you haven't actually answered my question I'm afraid. Are the black lines just the centreline's symbology offset to either side?

Comment: I was hoping to find a way of snapping to the offset symbology (black lines) rather than the features centreline. Is this possible?

Comment: No that's not possible in the way that you would like to. You can snap to a layer with an offset defined by the trace tool in the snapping toolbar but not with an offset defined by the layer's attribute. I would suggest you create a new layer buffered out from the centreline by the attribute and then snap to that. Is that an option?

Comment: Excellent, great service, thanks.